# Webpack having additional entry file and custom output location in nextJs

Tags: webpack, next.js

I need to import a javascript as a script using [Script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) tag inside _app.tsx in nextjs,
I tried these below steps

1. the problem is that file should be present in public path.
2. if i place the folder in public path, I cant able to do any imports/require (from src) as its excluded from webpack bundle.
3. I somehow managed to include it in `next.config.js`

   ```
    webpack(config) {
    return merge(config, {
      entry() {
        return config.entry().then((entry) => ({ ...entry, 
         'FireAnalyticsGen': '/public/scripts/FireAnalytics.js' }));
        },
     });
   }
   ```
4. but the output of the above generated bundle is generated inside .next/static/chunks/FireAnalyticsGen.js

I dont want to touch the main bundle, but I need to have this FireAnalyticsGen.js bundle in public folder. how to achieve that

Solved this by importing it directly from _next/static/chunks like below

```
 <Script src={'/_next/static/chunks/FireAnalyticsGen.js'}/>
```

Comment: You should be able to use the script from the `public` folder in the `Script` component using `src="/scripts/FireAnalytics.js"` as the source.

Comment: @juliomalves I tried that, but I couldnt able to use env variables and other helpers in public/FireAnalytics.js. Anyways Its solved. I have updated the solution in the question itself. but if you have any better approach let me know : )

Comment: You could pass the environment variables as `data-*` attributes to the `Script` component, then access the attributes in your script.